# Cannot connect to docker container (redis) in host mode

Tags: docker, redis

This probably just related to WSL in general but Redis is my use case.

This works fine and I can connect like:
`docker exec -it redis-1 redis-cli -c -p 7001 -a Password123`

But I cannot make any connections from my local windows pc to the container. I get

> Could not connect: Error 10061 connecting to host.docker.internal:7001. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

This is the same error when the container isn't running, so not sure if it's a docker issue or WSL?

```
version: '3.9'
  
services:     
  redis-cluster:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis-cluster
    command: redis-cli -a Password123 -p 7001 --cluster create 127.0.0.1:7001 127.0.0.1:7002 127.0.0.1:7003 127.0.0.1:7004 127.0.0.1:7005 127.0.0.1:7006 --cluster-replicas 1 --cluster-yes
    depends_on:
      - redis-1
      - redis-2
      - redis-3
      - redis-4
      - redis-5
      - redis-6
    network_mode: host
      

  redis-1:
    image: "redis:latest"
    container_name: redis-1

    network_mode: host

    entrypoint: >
      redis-server
      --port 7001
      --appendonly yes
      --cluster-enabled yes
      --cluster-config-file nodes.conf
      --cluster-node-timeout 5000
      --masterauth Password123
      --requirepass Password123
      --bind 0.0.0.0
      --protected-mode no

# Five more the same as the above
```

Comment: Could you provide the command you are using to connect from your windows/wsl shell?

Comment: redis-cli -h host.docker.internal -p 7001 -a Password123, will hang and redis-cli -p 7001 -a Password123, will show connection refused.   docker exec -it redis-1 redis-cli -c -p 7001 -a Password123 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to the provided `docker-compose.yml` file, container ports are not exposed, so they are unreachable from the outside (your windows/wls host). Check [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports) for the official reference. More about docker and ports [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports)

As an example for `redis-1` service, you should add the following to the definition.

```
...
redis-1:
  ports:
  - 7001:7001
  ...
...
```

The `docker exec ...` is working because the port is reachable from inside the container.

Comment: It's running in host mode (network_mode: host), so the ports are not applicable in the same manner.